# Unable to publish to Azure: Web deployment task failed

Tags: visual-studio, azure

I have been deploying my Web Service via Visual Studio for over a year. Today it suddenly started giving me the error: `Web deployment task failed.`
[image]

Things I have noticed:

1. I have two other projects in the same solution that deployed to Azure without an issue.
2. I am able to download and change files via Cloud Explorer in VS.
3. I cant preview changes.
4. Validate Connection fails.

Things that I have tried:

1. Reset the publish profile via Azure, downloaded and imported it.
2. Selected an existing App Service.
3. Ensured that WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM = false before downloading the latest
   publish profile.
4. Manually typed in the Username, Password from the Deployment Center

Hopefully someone can see something I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to publish after a few weeks and plenty of back-and-forths with Azure support. I'm not sure if it was just time that fixed the problem, but the last thing I did before it started working was Attach a Debugger to the App Service. Hope that helps!